Geonodes texture doesn't show in viewport
When I'm using texture to adjust geonode, I can't see the intermediate result in the viewport.
Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?
The gradient texture works properly, as you can see from the geometry:

When I try to visualize a texture by connecting viewer node, it goes completely black:

Even when I'm visualizing color ramp node with only white, it shows up black:



Could it be because of the view direction ? Because the X<0 part of the sphere is black (negative gradient), if the view direction is from negative X towards positive X, the "dark side of the sphere" is facing the observer. Do you try a top view, from Z>0 position ? (like this https://i.sstatic.net/65mttNTB.png)

Also, your object doesn't have the orange outline meaning it is selected : are you sure this is the nodes of the object the viewport is showing ?

@Lutzi I just use a white outline

@StefLAncien - I've looked at it from all angles, the thing is, it's creating the points in the correct way

At some point you disabled the viewer node in the viewport. Just enable it here  :


Thanks a LOT! =)
